# getting function itself among its parameters

Tags: javascript

have a simple function that is applying given attributes to DOM-element:

```
Object.prototype.setAttr = function(attr) { // attr is an object
  for ( var i in attr )
     this.setAttribute( i, atr[i] );
};
```

in addition to the passed parameters I'm getting function setAttr itself. can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: _"I'm getting function setAttr itself"_ ? What ? Show us your example!

Comment: It looks like `this` is messed up

Comment: don't add new methods in Object.prototype ever!

Comment: `Object.prototype.setAttr = function(attr) {
  console.log(attr);
  for ( var i in attr ) {
    console.log( i, attr[i] );
    this.setAttribute( i, attr[i] );
  }
};

var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.setAttr({height:200, width:200});`

Comment: @AndrewEvt ok but why?

Comment: @Antosha Shmonoff
1. All objects will recieve this methods. But do ALL OF THAM need it? - NO in 99.9% of cases
2. If YOU add a method called `setAttr` to `Object.prototype` in your module, and I will add it in my module, but it will return `undefined`. If someone will use both of tham - he will get errors in 99.9% of cases and bad logic in 100% of cases
3. Read more about prototype chains and optimization. Each new method added to the base `objects` (Object, Array, Function etc) will increase time for finding it (in calls like `for (var i in attr) {` too), and will slow down your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use hasOwnProperty to avoid looping through the prototype chain.

Since `attr` is an object and you have added `setAttr` to the prototype of `Object`, attr also has access to the `setAttr` method through its prototype chain.

```js
Object.prototype.setAttr = function(attr) { // attr is an object
  for (var i in attr) {
    if (attr.hasOwnProperty(i))
      this.setAttribute(i, attr[i]);
  }
};


item.setAttr({
  b: 1
});
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre> 
<p id="item">item</p>
```